# comment / uncomment specific entries in fstab

Tags: sed

I'm trying to create a script that can comment/uncomment specific lines in fstab.

this works fine if the argument is not a path...

```
# add comment
sed -i '/db1/s/^/#DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE /g' /etc/fstab

# remove comment
sed -i '/db1/s/^#DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE //g' /etc/fstab
```

However, if I try to use a variable with forward slash, it does not work.

If I have multiple entries like this, I only want to comment some of them.

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f40f5a40-4772-479e-9041-330c3afbfb40 /oradata/db1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f40f5a40-4772-479e-9041-330c3afbfb40 /oradata/db2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f40f5a40-4772-479e-9041-330c3afbfb40 /oradata/db3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I've tried all sorts of solutions and nothing works.. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You can use any delimiter in the sed substitute command (except those that you expect to be in the pattern). So you can use for example `sed 's%/path/file%%'`

Comment: No need to change delimiter here to append a `#` to an _anchor_

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @sudodus: I tried but I got this error: 
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `%'

Comment: @Hfux, Please show **exactly the command that failed** for you, and I will try to find a solution (if you still want a solution along that route).

Comment: thanks sudodus but I've fixed that issue and now I'm moving on to other issues :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
sed -i '/db1/s/^/#/g' /etc/fstab
```

Or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) with a stronger match:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^/#/g if m!/oradata/db1!' /etc/fstab
```

If you want stronger match with `sed`:

```
sed -i '/oradata\/db1/s/^/#/g' /etc/fstab
```

### Output

```
#/dev/disk/by-uuid/f40f5a40-4772-479e-9041-330c3afbfb40 /oradata/db1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f40f5a40-4772-479e-9041-330c3afbfb40 /oradata/db2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f40f5a40-4772-479e-9041-330c3afbfb40 /oradata/db3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: I tried with perl but I prefer to stick to shell if possible. the problem was when I passed the mountpoint as a variable. I suppose perl would be easier but I finally managed to get sed to work when I converted the mountpoint variable to another with escaped forward slashes.

Comment: I gave you a 'sed' solution. 'sed' like 'perl' are not shell builtins, it's tools. Did you tried my 'sed' solutions ?

Comment: hi Gilles, yes I tried. But using fwd slashes in the variables was not working out at first. I had to escape them before it could be used in sed. also, for some reason, using other delimiters (% or ! or &) didn't work.

you're right of course about sed/perl being tools. What I meant was that I'm used to using sed, so I wanted to stick with it.

Comment: fwd ? variables ? ...

Answer (score 0):

Well considering **SED** is **S**treaming **ED**itor you can better use `ed` as follows:

```
ed -s /etc/fstab <<< $'/db1/s/^/#/\n,p'
```

If the above looks good, just substitute `p` end by `w`

`p` = Print
`w` = Write

In case you are interested in replacing all occurrences globally then you'd run something like:

```
ed -s /etc/fstab <<< $'g/db1/s/^/#/\n,p'
```

Again, replace `p` by `w` to write to the file.

Because `<<<` would require `bash` there are other ways to get this done. Using Bourne shell with `printf`

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/db1/s/^/#/' w q | ed -s /etc/fstab
```

Or the Bourne shell without `printf`

```
ed -s /etc/fstab <<!
g/db1/s/^/#/
w
q
!
```

Comment: `bash` required here, better add this mention

Comment: @GillesQuenot , alright, a fair comment, though I assume bash is installed by default on most systems. I've added a few other examples that would not require bash explicitly.

Comment: FreeBSD like your avatar, is `sh`, not `bash` ;)

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of testing I found a solution to my problem.

Essentially I had to replace the MOUNTPOINT variable with another that contains the mountpoint path with escape characters added.

`MOUNTPOINTF="${MOUNTPOINT////\\/}`

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="./fstab"
TAG="#DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE "
COMMAND="do_mount"

f_usage(){
        echo "usage: sudo_mount_oradata1.sh -h"
        echo "       sudo_mount_oradata1.sh -m /oradata1 [-u]"
        exit 1;
}

f_mount() {
        if grep -q "${MOUNTPOINT}" $FILE ; then
                if grep -q "${TAG}" $FILE ; then
                        sed -i.bak "/${MOUNTPOINTF}/s/^${TAG}//g" $FILE
                else
                        echo "INFO: fstab does not contains a commented entry for ${MOUNTPOINT}."
                fi
        else
                echo "INFO: fstab does not contains an entry for ${MOUNTPOINT}."
        fi
}

f_unmount() {
        if grep -q "${MOUNTPOINT}" $FILE ; then
                if grep -q "${TAG}" $FILE ; then
                        echo "INFO: Entry for ${MOUNTPOINT} is already commented in fstab."
                else
                        sed -i.bak "/${MOUNTPOINTF}/s/^/${TAG} /g" $FILE
                fi
        else
                echo "INFO: fstab does not contains an entry for ${MOUNTPOINT}."
        fi
}

while getopts m:u opt
do
    case "$opt" in
                m) MOUNTPOINT="${OPTARG}" ; MOUNTPOINTF="${MOUNTPOINT////\\/}" ;;
                u) COMMAND="do_unmount" ;;
                *) f_usage ;;
        esac
done

clear
# remove leading whitespace from each line
sed -i "s/^[ \t]*//" $FILE

case "$COMMAND" in
        do_mount)   f_mount ;;
        do_unmount) f_unmount ;;
esac

# remove leading whitespace from each line
sed -i "s/^[ \t]*//" $FILE

# debug
echo;
cat $FILE
echo;
ls -lh $FILE*
exit 0
```